# how do i reset the random number generator python with minimal changes

Tags: python, reset

my assignment for school is trying to make a game with the following rules:
Create a program that randomly generates a number from 1 - 50. the user has to guess the number. When they guess,i should comment to help the user guess. Once they get the number i should tell the user how many guesses it took and ask the user if they would like to play again. If they do, create another number, if they do not, end the program.

my problem is that when i play again, my guess count doesnt reset and my"random number" doesnt change, please include a explanation of the changes for my code because im in a grade 11 course and just started learning to code, so im very new to this, thanks!
there is the codes:

```
import random
ran=random.randrange(1,50)
counter=0
guessed=False

def startgame():
    answer=input("would you like to play a game? enter 'yes' or 'no'")
    if answer == "yes":
        while guessed != True:
            game()
    if answer=="no":
        print("thanks for playing")

def game():
    global counter
    counter=counter+1
    x=input("chose a number between 0 and 50")
    if int(x)>ran:
        print("your value is too high")
    elif int(x)<ran<50:
        print("your value is too low")
    elif int(x)==ran:
        guessed=True
        answer=input("that is correct! it took you "+ str(counter) +" tries,     "+"would you like to play again? enter 'yes' or 'no'")
        if answer == "yes":
            main()
        if answer=="no":
            print("thanks for playing")

def main():
    startgame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have declared `ran=random.randrange(1,50)` in the global scope so this would be called only once when you run the script, to get the desired behavior, you should initialize it at each call to the `startgame()` and pass it as a parameter to each function.

```
def main():
    ran=random.randrange(1,50)
    startgame(ran)

def startgame(ran):
    #your function here.

def game(ran):
    #Your function here
```

Another idea is to declare the `ran` as a global variable and change it's value at each call to `game()` function, this would be the minimal change that you can do to get the desired behavior, But `globals` should not be used as a lot of global variables make the code unmanageable.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `ran` as a global variable. Being a global variable, it will be initialized once. It would be better if you call a function let's say `get_random_no` that will return random numbers every time. Inside that function, we will write the logic to return random numbers.

```
import random
counter=0
guessed=False

def get_random_no():
    ran = random.randrange(1,50)
    return ran

def startgame():
    answer=input("would you like to play a game? enter 'yes' or 'no'")
    if answer == "yes":
        while guessed != True:
            game()
    if answer=="no":
        print("thanks for playing")

def game():
    global counter
    counter=counter+1
    ran = get_random_no()
    x=input("chose a number between 0 and 50")
    if int(x)>ran:
        print("your value is too high")
    elif int(x)<ran<50:
        print("your value is too low")
    elif int(x)==ran:
        guessed=True
        answer=input("that is correct! it took you "+ str(counter) +" tries,     "+"would you like to play again? enter 'yes' or 'no'")
        if answer == "yes":
            main()
        if answer=="no":
            print("thanks for playing")

def main():
    startgame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```